# How do I group implementations under interfaces in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I downloaded some example code from [github](https://github.com/Mallioch/Evolving-Ajax-And-ASPNETMVC-Practices) and saw that the BookRepository.cs class was grouped beneath the IBookRepository.cs interface.  Maybe this is a newbie question, but how do they do that?

[image: A snapshot from visual studio 2010 of an implementation grouped beneath an interface in the solution explorer.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*They* might have used a [custom generator tool](http://www.drewnoakes.com/snippets/WritingACustomCodeGeneratorToolForVisualStudio/):

[image]

And here's another [blog post](http://www.christophercrooker.com/visual-studio-2010-rc-custom-tool-for-code-generation-and-jquery14-with-intellisense-for-scriptsharp) on this topic.

Or *they* might have simply grouped it like this in the [corresponding `.csproj` file](https://github.com/Mallioch/Evolving-Ajax-And-ASPNETMVC-Practices/blob/master/EvolvingAjaxAndASPNETMVCPractices/EvolvingAjaxAndASPNETMVCPractices.csproj):

```
<Compile Include="Code\BookRepository.cs">
  <DependentUpon>IBookRepository.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Code\IBookRepository.cs" />
```

Comment: Yup, they edited the .csproj file.  Thanks a bunch.  I couldn't quite find the right combinations of terms to find an answer via Google.